# How does MongoDB treat find().sort() queries with respect to single and compound indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I have a typical `find().sort()` query that I run on my mongo collection.

```
db.collection.find({field1:1}).sort({field2:1})
```

Now, say I have three indexes on this collection:

1. single index on `field1`
2. single index on `field2`
3. compound index on `field1` and `field2` - `{field1:1,field2:1}`

Now my question, how does mongoDB treat the above query? What are the indexes that will be used in a query like that- two single indexes or the one compound index?

If I remove the compound index, does it in fact make use of the two single indexes but slowing down?

Comment: very helpful: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: @Disposer so it uses a compound index right...is it correct to expect the query to use the single indexes and to get slow if there's no compound index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your point, this might help:

Assuming you have these documents for sample

```
{
    field1 : 1,
    field2 : 2,
},
{
    field1 : 2,
    field2 : 3,
},
{
    field1 : 1,
    field2 : 4,
}
```

Step 1: you have index just for **filed1** (name of index **field1_1**)}:
perform the : `db.test3.find({field1:1}).sort({field2:1})`

the mongo uses **field1_1** index to search in document. the result of .explain() is:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 2,
"nscannedObjects" : 2,
"nscanned" : 2,
```

Step 2: add your compound index, name it **field1_1_field2_1**, now you have 2 index for field 1.

perform `find().sort()` query, you will have

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1_field2_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 2,
"nscannedObjects" : 2,
"nscanned" : 2,
```

**Concolusion:**

if you use `db.test3.find({field1:1}).sort({field2:1})`, the mongo will use `field1_1_field2_1` index.

if you use `db.test3.find({field1:1})`, the mongo will use `field1_1` index.

I your case, If you have just **field1_1_field2_1** index and you are performing `db.test3.find({field1:1})`, the mongo will use `field1_1_field2_1` index as well.

Comment: Which is a perfect description why it does not make sense to have single field indices in case the field already is indexed in a compound index.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg true, though I was more concerned with not having a compound index :-)