# CosmosDB MongoDB 3.6 fails sort() query with compounded index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Newby MongoDB & CosmosDB user here, I've read the answer to this question [How does MongoDB treat find().sort() queries with respect to single and compound indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739127/how-does-mongodb-treat-find-sort-queries-with-respect-to-single-and-compound) and the offocial MongoDB docs and I believe my index creation mirrors that answer so I am leaning towards this being a CosmosDB issue but reading their documentation CosmosDB 3.6 supports compounded indexes as well, so I am at a loss right now.

I am able to run sort() queries like `db.Videos.find().sort({"PublishedOn": 1})` from the mongo command line on a collection with an index created as `db.Videos.createIndex({"PublishedOn": 1})` or `db.Videos.createIndex({"PublishedOn": -1})`.

And when I add a 'where' clause to the find like this `db.Videos.find({"IsPinned": false}).sort({"PublishedOn": 1})` the above index still works.

However I now have document look ups which I want to avoid, so I drop the above single field index and create a compounded index like this `db.Videos.createIndex({"IsPinned": 1, "PublishedOn": 1})` or `db.Videos.createIndex({"PublishedOn": 1, "IsPinned": 1})` but now the query always fails with the error `The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded.`.

Is this a limitation of CosmosDB or is my 'ordering' in the index bad?

Comment: Cosmos is an independent implementation that does not share any underlying server code with MongoDB, so you cannot infer expected behaviour based on what a MongoDB deployment supports. For example, the error `The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded` is specific to Cosmos' API. I expect the index on `{"PublishedOn": 1, "IsPinned": 1}` should be usable (or rather, would be used by MongoDB based on your query). It seems Cosmos may require different index definitions to support sorting. Perhaps the `PublishedOn` sort order in the index has to match the query?

Comment: You are absolutely right that CosmosDB is not MongoDB, I hope I didn't infer that with my question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with CosmosDB is that it expects all `WHERE` fields to be used in the `GROUP BY` clause as well in exactly the same order else it won't use the index.

Creating an index as `db.Videos.createIndex({"IsPinned": 1, "PublishedOn": 1})` and then updating the query to be `db.Videos.find({"IsPinned": false}).sort({"IsPinned": 1, "PublishedOn": 1})` works like a charm.

I inferred this from reading the CosmosDB documentation on indexing policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) as the MongoDB documentation suddenly stops after the index creation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing) section.